# Why calling messagebox in tkinter pops up tkinter root window?

Tags: python, tkinter

When I am trying to write a syntax for messagebox in tkinter like this

'''
'root=tkinter.Tk()'
'Messagebox.Showinfo()'
'''

It is popping up root window although I have not called root.mainloop()
How is this happening?

Comment: Thanks for responding TheLizzard, Simply running root=tkinter. Tk() is not popping up root window, it is when I am also writing messagebox. Showinfo() syntax along with first one. I am using pycharm IDE.

Comment: If you want to hide the window, just use `root.withdraw()`.

Comment: That's ok but I want to use the root window to popup at the last line of code so that I could write more codes after the messagebox.otherwise the code is hanging at the messagebox.info() syntax. I want to know why it happens when we call messagebox.showinfo() .

Comment: The `showinfo` function creates a `Toplevel` and calls `.wait_window()` which is something like a `.mainloop()` that runs until that pop up is closed. For more info please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28388346/11106801).

Comment: Thanks TheLizzard.. It is convincing to me