# How to wait till a window is closed on Tkinter before continuing function?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to make a simple POS system with user accounts.
What I want to happen is for it to wait until the `SubtotalOrder` class window is closed before the rest of the function is completed because the variable `customerProfile` isn't assigned to the correct data until that class window is closed.

```
def subtotalOrder(self):
    SubtotalOrder(self.win)

    conn = sqlite3.connect("inventory.db")
    cur = conn.cursor()
    print(customerProfileID)
    today = date.today()
    cur.execute(
        "INSERT INTO orders (cusID, date, subtotal) VALUES ('{0}', '{1}', '{2}')".format(
            customerProfileID, today.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"), self.subtotal))
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE OrderID = (SELECT MAX(OrderID) FROM orders)")
    orderID = cur.fetchone()

    for items in self.orderList:
        cur.execute(
            "INSERT INTO transactions (OrderID, ItemID) VALUES ('{0}', '{1}')".format(
                orderID[1], items[1]))

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

Comment: research [wait_window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28388346/what-does-thewait-window-method-do)

Comment: The universal widget method `a_widget.wait_window(win)` waits until window *`win`* is destroyed.